# Unable to access a variable from controller in View pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a search field where user can input feedback token number and
respective searched feedback form will appear.

hence in feedback_controller.rb file :

```
  def find_token
    @result_feedback = Feedback.find_by_token(params[:token_no]) #61153892 
    redirect_to feedbackresult_path
  end
```

in route :

```
  match '/feedbackresult' => 'feedbacks#searchedfeedback'
```

in views/feedbacks/searchedfeedback.html.erb

```
  <%= @result_feedback.name %>
```

It's throwing following Error message :

```
NoMethodError in Feedbacks#searchedfeedback
Showing /home/ajay/Documents/ROR/CAP/app/views/feedbacks/searchedfeedback.html.erb where line #1 raised:
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails initializes a new instance of controller for every request. So a redirected action can't share the instance variables of the action from which the redirect was called. In other words, your `searchedfeedback` action has no knowledge of the `@result_feedback` instance.

Try this:

```
def search_feedback
  if params[:token_no]
    @result_feedback = Feedback.find_by_token(params[:token_no])
  end
end
```

And your view `search_feedback.html.erb` should look like this:

```
<%= form_tag :search_feedback, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :token_no %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>

<% if @result_feedback %>
  <%= @result_feedback.name %>
<% end %>
```

If you want to keep your controller action clean, use a `before_filter` / `before_action`:

```
  before_action :find_token

  # ...

private

  def find_token
    if params[:token_no]
      @result_feedback = Feedback.find_by_token(params[:token_no])
    end
  end
```